# Chrome dont send cookie with allow cors

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, axios

i try to send POST request from localhost to another domain.
I set for cookie `SameSite = None ; Secure`

how it require in
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#see_also

[image]

Request made to HTTPS server.
Using AXIOS with

```
{ withCredentials: true }
```

But in request information i dont see that cookie send

[image]

What is problem? What did i miss?

On server side i use this:

```
app.use(
    cors({
        credentials: true,
        //origin: true,
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
      callback(null, true);
    },
    })
);
```

its give me in response headers:

[image]

Comment: That's not how cookies work. Cookies are scoped to a specific domain, and possibly subdomains thereof (if you the cookie was set with a valid `Domain` attribute). In your case, the cookie will only get sent to origins whose host is `localhost`, never to `https://whatever.cyclic.app`.

Comment: The `SameSite` attribute doesn't change _where_ the cookie is sent, only _from where_ it can come.

Comment: @jub0bs "withCredentials = true approach which enables sharing the credentials such as cookies, authorized headers between different domains."

Comment: I don't understand your last comment, sorry. `withCredentials` is only going to attach credentials (usually cookies) to a request if the cookies in question are associated with the request's destination. `withCredentials` does not mean that cookies will be attached to _all_ requests, regardless of where they go.